# What is the correct way to get the rendered fields values in a block view twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a block on the main page of my website that displays most recent news stories from the *News* page (3 latest entries). This is a view, here is its settings:

[image]

I'm trying to make this block look better. As this is a view, I use *block--views-block--news-block-1.html.twig* template file for my purpose. All I wanted was to get the rendered field values in it to wrap each of them in a *<div>* with its own css class. I tried many times and through trial and error finally I wrote the following code:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'block',
    'block-' ~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
    'block-' ~ plugin_id|clean_class,
  ]
%}
<div class="container">
    <section{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ title_prefix }}
            <h2 class="article_title">District News</h2>
        {{ title_suffix }}
        {% block content %}
            <ul class="content article_list">
                {% for row in content['#view'].result %}
                    <li class="article_item">
                        <div class="article_item-header">
                            <div class="article_release_date">
                                {{ content['#view'].field['published_at'].value(row)|date("d.m.Y") }}
                            </div> 
                            {{ content['#view'].field['title'].getItems(row) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="article_description">
                            {{ content['#view'].field['body'].getItems(row) }}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endblock %}
        <div class="article_read_more">
            <a href="/news">View All</a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

It works satisfactorily: I see the markup and variables in this block on the main page exactly as I designed them. But I can't say that it works just perfectly because when I go to "Recent log messages", I see errors coming from this *.twig* template file. The error message is:
`User error: "raw" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php)`. When I delete my twig file, the error doesn't occur anymore.
So my question is: What is the correct way to achieve the same markup without such errors? Maybe my approach is totally wrong and I should change it. Or maybe my approach is correct, but there is a little mistake in my code? Anyway, I'd like to know why do I get such error in the log and how can I avoid it. Please, help me.

Comment: I'd recommend updating your view to display a view mode of the news node, then you can do all the logic of which fields display and how they display for each news item right in a dedicated template.

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to theme fields inside the block is not a best practice.

The approach mentioned in the comments by **sonfd** is a very good one.

Otherwise, you can theme each field in the view by overriding the field template like:

```
views-view-field--{views machine name}--{page or block machine name}--{field name}.html.twig
```

This would be a better approach.

Hope this answers your question.